# Twitter, Facebook - is there any way to get the original images of avatars?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, twitter, avatar

Through RoR gem OmniAuth is possible to get an informations about the users, who log-in to the application through their Twitter or Facebook account. Both of these social sites in their API offers among other also the avatar, what's great. 
The worse thing is, that the size of image is 50x50px (I know, avatar).

Exist any way, how to get the original image, from that was created avatar? (The reason why I want it is, that I would like to display a photo of user in the bigger size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. GET `/${USER_ID}/picture?type=large`; the response is a 302 redirect so you can obtain the url from the response header.  See the docs for the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) for other values for `type`.  (Contrary to the docs it looks like an access token is required.)  This doesn't get you a particularly large image.
2. GET `/${USER_ID}/albums` and find the album with `type=profile`.  GET the photos in this album with `/${ALBUM_ID}/photos`: I *think* the first photo is the current avatar (it is for me), and more sizes are available than with the first method.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get from gravatar[1] with email.

1. http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement